# Unity Google Play Update 64 bit problem, its already includes 64 bit

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play

i checked ARMv7, ARM64, x86 and exported.
But When i try to upload google play, i get that Error "This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement"
I cannot understand
Please Help

Backend il2cpp
ARMv7
ARM64
x86

This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement

The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to uncheck x86 and try again. (check only ARMv7 and ARM64)

Comment: Thank you, it worked but why x86 is not necessary ?

Comment: Unity does not support x86_64, so you where missing 64-bit support on this architecture. There is no support for x86_64 planned, in [fact x86 got deprecated and is removed in the current Unity 2019.3 release](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/03/05/android-support-update-64-bit-and-app-bundles-backported-to-2017-4-lts/).